# Height of header container is dynamic

Tags: html, css, height

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
           <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            </head>
         <body>
                <div class = "wrapper">
                    <header>
                                <div class = "CentralHeader">
                                    <div class = "LinkBar" id = "HeaderBar" >All</div>
                                <div class = "SampleMenu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href = "#Movies">Movies</a></li>
                                    <li><a href = "#Events">Events</a></li>
                                    <li><a href = "#Sports">Sports</a></li>
                                    <li><a href = "#Plays">Plays</a></li>       
                                </ul>
                               </div>
                        </div>
                </header>
                <main>
                    <div class = "main">
                        <div class = "TopMovies" >
                        </div>
                        <div class = "JustForYou">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
            </div>
            </body>
            <style type="text/css">
            .wrapper{
                height: 100vh;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction:column;
            }
            header{
                height: 400px;
                border-bottom: 4px solid beige;
              }
            main{
                flex:1
            }

         .LinkBar {
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 140px;
        height: 37px;
        border: 1px solid #c02c3a;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-left: 300px;
        background-color: #c02c3a;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 9px;
        color: white;
        display: inline-block;
        }
        div.SampleMenu ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            width: 140px;
            background-color: Grey;
            margin-left: 300.5px;
            padding: 0;
            margin-top: 0px;
            display: none;
            border-top: 2px solid #fff;
        }
       div.SampleMenu ul li {
        color: White;
        padding: 0;
        }
           div.SampleMenu ul li a {
            color: white;
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: large;
            text-align: center;
        }
          #HeaderBar:hover~.SampleMenu ul,
            .SampleMenu ul:hover {
            display: block;
            }
          .main{
            width:auto;
            height: 500px;
            border:2px groove red;
            }
            </style>
            </body>
            </html>
```

In the above segment,the container space of "header" is altered on hovering the LinkBar.On hovering ,the dropdown is displayed with the mentioned height for the header but  in normal state,header height is decreased.When the CSS property for the wrapper tag is removed ,the functionality i.e container space for header is available as mentioned in CSS (400px).What is causing the height of the header to be dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the menu to overlap the header, you need to add "position: absolute;" to the menu (div.SampleMenu ul in your case to be specific) and "position: relative;" to the header.

You should read more about the ways of positioning and how they interact with each other.

Comment: I don't want the menu to overlap with the below table.I want the table to be spaced so that it doesn't collide with menu